# Avoid ffmpeg to lose the flv files keyframes

Tags: linux, conversion, ffmpeg, flv

I use ffmpeg to convert my files, but when I do so, I lose the keyframes metadata from my flv files.

The command I use right now is:

```
$/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i %s -ab 96k -ar 44100 -b 500k -r 25 -f flv %s
```

How can I avoid ffmpeg to delete the keyframes info?

Regards

Zeeshan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the metadata can be lost during any conversion step, it is always possible to regenerate them later.

There are a few tools that can be used to regenerate keyframe informations, including:

- [flvmeta](http://code.google.com/p/flvmeta/) (tool that I have developed)
- [yamdi](http://yamdi.sourceforge.net/)
- [flvtool2](http://rubyforge.org/projects/flvtool2/)
- [flvtool++](http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/flvtool++/)
- [flvmdi](http://www.buraks.com/flvmdi/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following argument:

```
-map_meta_data 0:0
```

This should copy the metadata of the first stream of the input file to the first stream of the output file. More information can be found here: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC12

Comment: Did not work, this is how my command looks after adding the argument you told me: '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i %s -map_meta_data 0:0 -ab 96k -ar 44100 -b 500k -r 25 -f flv %s'

Comment: Is this correct? I am sorry, I am new to linux.

Comment: You might need to look at the documentation there to see if the option I showed needs to be modified for the video you are using.