# Batch Edit Keyframe Metadata FLV Recorded Stream Video

Tags: script, metadata, flv, video-conversion, video-streaming

I recorded an FLV stream, but the resulting video has an awkward metadata quirk that prevents successful conversion to other formats. Here is a snapshot of the keyframes at the beginning of the FLV as displayed by the Fix FLV tool in [Jaksta](http://www.jaksta.com/) (aka [Replay Media Catcher](http://www.applian.com/download-videos/)):

[image]

The first several keyframes have a timestamp of zero. And then it jumps to 4381554 miliseconds and continues normally from there. This is due to the fact that I started recording 5:52:42 into the live-stream. I would like to do two things:

1. Remove the keyframes with the zero timestamp at the beginning.
2. Subtract 4381554 from ALL the keyframes so that the first one starts at zero.

Let me note that this video plays in Adobe Media Player, but starts at the 5:52:42 mark, even though you can't actually jump to the range between 0:00:00 and 5:52:41.

An answer to this [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/286074/avoid-ffmpeg-to-lose-the-flv-files-keyframes) outlines some tools that could be used to generate keyframe information for an FLV file, but I don't think any of them achieve what I would like.

I basically would like to write a script, but I don't know how to export and more importantly **import** keyframe metadata into an flv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tools in your link, [flvtool2](http://rubyforge.org/projects/flvtool2/) should do what you demand. See also this article :
[Change / Insert FLV Metadata Values (timestamp, dimensions) with Flvtool2](http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2007/04/15/change-insert-flv-metadata-values-timestamp-dimensions-with-flvtool2/)

If this doesn't solve the problem, see this thread for multiple other suggestions :
[Fix/repair flv files (make flv files seekable,playable,inject metadata,fix duration)](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/showthread.php?s=64cb895a6d8ea9d37c4a55d4134b2999&t=5751).